Number of distinct minimal fundamental cycle matrix of rank $k$
For a graph $G=(E,V)$ and a fundamental cycle basis $C_1,\ldots,C_k$, we can create a incident matrix $M$ between the edges and the fundamental cycles. Namely, $M_{i,j}=1$ if $e_i\in C_j$, and $M_{i,j}=0$ otherwise.
Matrix of this form are fundamental cycle matrix. It is minimal, if no two rows are the same.
Two matrix $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic if through row and column exchange operations, $M$ can be transformed into $N$.
What is the number of minimal fundamental cycle matrix with rank $k$ (up to isomorphism)?

Interesting problem. If I'm not mistaking, we can also see it as counting unsigned network matrices (https://www.kuniga.me/blog/2013/06/30/network-matrices.html) (up to isomorphism, without duplicated rows, and the graph is a perfect matching -- to ensure each cycle contains an edge by itself). Not sure how helpful it is.
